# yum update dependency in CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos, yum

After installing a rpm, by running

```
sudo yum update
```

in CentOS 6.6, I am getting the error

```
Error: Package: qgis-python-2.8.1-3.el7.centos.x86_64 (neteler-QGIS-2.8-Wien)
   Requires: libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit)
```

However,  `libpython2.7.so.1.0`    (or at least its soft link) can be seen in  the `/usr/lib`. 
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you install something outside of `yum` that gave you that?  I can't find a package that provides it myself.  You can see if you have a repo that has a package with it with `yum whatprovides '*/libpython2.7.so.1.0'` and see if that turns up a package that you'll need to make sure is installed

Comment: Agree with @EricRenouf. Your question also has a few inconsistencies. You ask about CentOS 6.6, but the error is about a `el7.centos` rpm, so that's from the wrong release. It's also a 64-bit rpm, but you have `/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0`, do you also have `/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0`? CentOS 6.6 should have `libpython2.6.so.1.0`. Seems like you might be mixing rpms from different releases and/or architectures.

Comment: Agree with both. OP is probably trying to install those 3rd party packages: http://courses.neteler.org/inofficial-rpms-qgis-2-8-epel7/ ... well they are for CentOS7 and should hence also work for Fedora 19/20, and they have separate repos for 21 and 22.

But they will **not** work on CentOS 6.6